# Using go/ast for iota declarations

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, iota

I've been working with go/ast to parse go source code and copy it into another file as part of a vendoring exercise. I've got most things handled - functions, types etc - but I'm struggling with const declarations which use iota. I'm iterating through the items in ast.File.Scope.Objects and copying over the source for objects with Scope.Outer == nil and their Decl == ast.ValueSpec, basically implying top level variables and constants.

In a block of type:

```
const (
    a = iota
    b
    c
    d
)
```

...each one of them registers as a separate object, which is fair enough. However, I'm struggling to assign them with values because the objects can also be out of order when I'm iterating through them. I'm able to see the value as ast.Object.Data for these, but it also seems off when it's set to 1 << iota and so on. Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can get a grouped const declaration with the correct iota values assigned?

Thank you!

Comment: You can type check the ast with `go/types` and that package has [`TypeAndValue`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/#TypeAndValue) which you can then use the get the constant's values.

Comment: The go/ast package maintains source code order.  You can copy the constant values as is without evaluating iota.  As the previous comment states, use go/types to evaluate iota.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot, via go/types.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'm currently iterating through the items in ast.File.Scope.Objects, and here I'm not seeing things in order. I'm also checking within each iteration if Scope.Outer == nil, to verify if it's global. Could I trouble you by asking for directions to obtaining these nodes in order? Thanks!

Comment: Iterate through [File.Decls](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#File.Decls).   If the decl is [*GenDecl](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#GenDecl) with Tok = Token.CONST, then it's constant.  Iterate through the decl's specs to examine each value.  It's all in source code order.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick! I'll write up a detailed answer for this thread soon.

Comment: @CeriseLimón thank you for the comment, I was running into this problem (same as OP) and your comment helped me reach the solution. I ended up doing a loop twice: once on the scope object list (to get the const values) and once on the declaration list to get things in order and resolve the type name.

Answer (score 3):

I was working on this problem for the [`exhaustive`](https://github.com/nishanths/exhaustive) analyzer, which, during its enum discovery phase, needs to find constant values.

---

**Playground:** https://play.golang.org/p/nZLmgE4rJZH

Consider the following ConstDecl. It comprises of 3 ConstSpec, and each ConstSpec has 2 names. (This example uses iota, but the approach below should work generally for any ConstDecl.)

```golang
package example

const (
    A, B = iota, iota * 100 // 0, 0
    _, D                    // 1, 100
    E, F                    // 2, 200
)
```

With `go/ast` and `go/types` (or [`x/tools/go/packages`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/go/packages)), we can obtain a *ast.GenDecl representing the above ConstDecl and a *types.Info for the package.

```golang
var decl *ast.GenDecl
var info *types.Info
```

The following will be true of `decl`.

```
decl.Tok == token.CONST
```

To obtain the constant values, we can do:

```golang
func printValuesConst(decl *ast.GenDecl, info *types.Info) {
    for _, s := range decl.Specs {
        v := s.(*ast.ValueSpec) // safe because decl.Tok == token.CONST
        for _, name := range v.Names {
            c := info.ObjectOf(name).(*types.Const)
            fmt.Println(name, c.Val().ExactString())
        }
    }
}
```

This will, as expected, print:

```
A 0
B 0
_ 1
D 100
E 2
F 200
```

### Side note: `var` instead of `const`

Note that the code above works for `const` blocks; for a `var` block we will have to obtain the value using `v.Values[i]` (assuming a value exists at the index `i`).

**Playground**: https://play.golang.org/p/f4mYjXvsvHB

```
decl.Tok == token.VAR
```

```
func printValuesVar(decl *ast.GenDecl, info *types.Info) {
    for _, s := range decl.Specs {
        v := s.(*ast.ValueSpec) // safe because decl.Tok == token.VAR
        for i, name := range v.Names {
            if len(v.Values) <= i {
                fmt.Println(name, "(no AST value)")
                continue
            }
            tv := info.Types[v.Values[i]]
            if tv.Value == nil {
                fmt.Println(name, "(not constant value)")
                continue
            }
            fmt.Println(name, tv.Value.ExactString())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `*ast.File` type:

- `Scope.Objects` tells you the names and values of the const declarations, but does not have them in the correct order, so you can't use it to infer the type.
- `Decls` gives you the declarations in order, so you can use it to infer the type

You can iterate on both list. First on the `Scope.Objects` to get the const values, then on `Decls` to infer the type.

Samplecode on the playground: https://go.dev/play/p/yEz6G1Kqoe3

I'll provide a sample code below. To make it more concrete, there are two assumptions:

- We have a `file *ast.File` which we got from the parser package (for example, by calling `parser.ParseDir(..)`
- We have a list of enum type name we want to get the consts for.

```golang
type EnumInfo struct {
    Name     string
    TypeName string // base type
    Consts   []ConstValue
}

type ConstValue struct {
    Name  string
    Value any // int or string
}
```

and we have a `enumTypesMap map[string]*EnumInfo` that maps a type name to the EnumInfo object.

The purpose of the following snippet is to populate the `Consts` list of the `EnumInfo` struct. We assume we have the name and base typename via other means (e.g. reflection).

Modify to suit your own purposes

```golang
type EnumInfo struct {
    Name     string
    TypeName string // base type
    Consts   []ConstValue
}

type ConstValue struct {
    Name  string
    Value any // int or string
}

func PopulateEnumInfo(enumTypesMap map[string]*EnumInfo, file *ast.File) {
    // phase 1: iterate scope objects to get the values
    var nameValues = make(map[string]any)

    for _, object := range file.Scope.Objects {
        if object.Kind == ast.Con {
            nameValues[object.Name] = object.Data
        }
    }

    // phase 2: iterate decls to get the type and names in order
    for _, decl := range file.Decls {
        genDecl, ok := decl.(*ast.GenDecl)
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        if genDecl.Tok != token.CONST {
            continue
        }
        var enumInfo *EnumInfo
        for _, spec := range genDecl.Specs {
            valSpec := spec.(*ast.ValueSpec)
            if typeIdent, ok := valSpec.Type.(*ast.Ident); ok {
                enumInfo = enumTypesMap[typeIdent.String()]
            }
            if enumInfo != nil {
                for _, nameIdent := range valSpec.Names {
                    name := nameIdent.String()
                    if name == "_" {
                        continue
                    }
                    value := nameValues[name]
                    enumInfo.Consts = append(enumInfo.Consts, ConstValue{
                        Name:  name,
                        Value: value,
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```